# Awk one liner to copy last field to each member of line

Tags: awk, sed

Looking for a awk one liner for formatting some text in a file of this format where number of fields and number of lines are arbitrary:

```
abcd,abce,test1
bbcd,bbee,bbvc,test2
ccdd,ccbb,ccbd,ccab,testxyz
```

Where output is where the last field in each line is appended to each field in the line:

```
abcd,test1
abce,test1
bbcd,test2
bbee,test2
bbvc,test2
ccdd,testxyz
ccbb,testxyz
ccbd,testxyz
ccab,testxyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all lines have at least 2 fields:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i,$NF}' file
```

can do what you expect.

If there can be lines with just one field and you could just print it:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i,$NF; if(NF==1) print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/,(.*(,[^,]*))$/\2\n\1/;P;D' file
```

If the line contains 2 or more commas, replace the first comma by a comma, the last field and a newline, print the first line, delete the first line and repeat.